歯に噛んで why over を?

キャラメルを持っていたあなたを憎まずにいられなかった。
美味そうに、
幸せそうに、
香り立つほど歯に噛んで。

Why is に used in this sentence over を?

歯に噛む is not an idiomatic phrase, but I believe the particle に is being used here as a direction/destination marker. This usage of に is similar to that in 袋に詰める or クリップに挟む. The phrase 歯に噛む ("to bite into one's teeth") sounds unusual, but since キャラメル is a sticky food, I imagine it likely describes a situation where caramel gets stuck between your teeth while chewing it in a unique way.
Since it is impossible to bite your own teeth, saying 歯を噛む would definitely be incorrect.
